# when passing List<object> to a web api from jquery ajax, count is always ZERO

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

Web API is as below

```
 [Route("saveFieldGroupForPayerRequestType")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public HttpResponseMessage SaveFieldGroupForPayerRequestType(List<PayerReqTypeFieldGroupMap> PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists)
    {
 // Business Logic           
    }
```

The Model is as below

```
public class PayerReqTypeFieldGroupMap
{
    public string TPSPayerId { get; set; }
    public string RequestTypeCode { get; set; }
    public string FieldGroupDesc { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

And the JQuery ajax call is as below

```
var PyrReqTypeFieldGrpMapsObject;
var PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists=[];

PyrReqTypeFieldGrpMapsObject = {                    
                TPSPayerId: "ddd",
                RequestTypeCode :  "ddd",
                FieldGroupDesc : "ddd",
                IsEnabled : true
              }; 
 PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists.push(PyrReqTypeFieldGrpMapsObject);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'application/json',
        data: PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists,
        url: api + "saveFieldGroupForPayerRequestType",                                                
        success: function (data) {                  
                            },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){                                   
                            }
        }).done(function (e) {
                            });
```

The issue is , from my ajax call, the web api method gets hit, but the count is always 0.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change you Ajax I test you need to stringify the data befor send to server, its working

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json', // data type to send sever
        dataType: 'json', // return type of data from server
        data: JSON.stringify(PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists),
        url: 'http://localhost:8591/saveFieldGroupForPayerRequestType',
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    }).done(function (e) {
    });
```

**JSON.stringify():**
A common use of JSON is to exchange data to/from a web server.When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string.Convert a JavaScript object into a string with JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform **JSON.stringify** of **PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists** before hitting the web api.

```
data: JSON.stringify(PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists)
```

And add contenttype as well.

```
contentType: 'application/json', // send the data type to server.
```

Comment: add contentType: 'application/json' in your ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `contentType` property value to `"application/json"`. Also you need to stringify the `data` property value before sending the request.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists),
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: api + "saveFieldGroupForPayerRequestType",
    success: function (data) {},
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
}).done(function (e) {

});
```

---

### Two more points

1. You should use `done`, `fail` and `always` instead of `success`, `error` and `complete` as pointed out in the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). The last three callbacks are deprecated.
2. The `datatype` property should be `dataType`. Also the `'application/json'` value is not allowed for this property. [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) says:

   > The available data types are text, html, xml, json, jsonp, and script.

So, you could use this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: api + "saveFieldGroupForPayerRequestType",
    data: JSON.stringify(PayerReqTypeFieldGrpMapLists),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"      
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

}).always(function () {

});
```

Comment: Well You need to mention jquery version jQuery 3.0